# Invoking a file from AWS lambda handler.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have node.js file(i.e.`abc.js`) which will give the output when i run in my node.js editor. I want to run the same file in `AWS Lambda`.For that, I created a lambda and moved `abc.js` to there. To run, it seems i need to implement my `abc.js` file in handler.js(i.e.in lambda way means callback etc).

Is there any way to trigger `abc.js` from `handler.js` rather than implementing again the same thing in `handler.js`?

Checked regarding the above usecase but didn't find much on google.

**Updated**

My abc.js file

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({
    region: "ap-south-1"
   });

// Create S3 service object
s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params= {};
 s3.listBuckets(params, bucketList);
function bucketList(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else   
  {   
        console.log(data)
  }
}
```

My handler.js in lambda and modifying it based on my interpretation of your answer.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const abc = require('./abc.js');
    // TODO implement
abc.bucketList();     
};
```

This is the error i am getting

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "abc.bucketList is not a function",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:5:5)"
  ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Require your file

```
const abc = require('./abc.js');
```

And in the handler function call your code

```
abc.yourExportedMethod();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate ? When i tried `abc.yourExportedMethod();` in my handler.js it is throwing error. Please check my Updated Section in my question

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues inside of your abc.js file.

Try this snippet:

```
const abc = async function() 
{
    try
    {
        const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        let s3 = new AWS.S3({region: "ap-south-1", apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
        let params= {};
        const s3Response = await s3.listBuckets(params).promise();

        console.log(s3Response); // your list of buckets 

    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        console.error(ex);
    }
}

export default abc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line at the bottom of your **abc.js**

```
exports.bucketList = bucketList
```

and the rest will work as you expect it to.